# UITableViewCell can't get the right width with systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm using autolayout+xib to construct the cell , and the cell's height is dynamic , so I use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to get the height for the

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

my code is like this:

[image]
and this will print the logs like this:
[image]

so we can find that ,the size return from `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` can be more wider than my device screen (iPhone5:320 point), how could this happen? (and I have tried to add the `layoutIfNeeded` and `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, but the problem still exist.

And i was using Xcode 6 ,which xib file size is not fixed.

PS: my view contains a multiline label ,I print the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of this label , and I found that the preferredMaxLayoutWidth is also very big , may be this is the problem .but how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah ,it's the problem of wrong preferredMaxLayoutWidth ,fix by add this line in the custom cell's updateConstraints
    self.contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.contentLabel.frame);

#### PS

in fact ,i found the cell's subView may not get the correct width after the cell's layoutSubview called , so if you want to make the preferredMaxLayoutWidth based on the label's width , you'd better set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth in the layoutIfNeeded not in the layoutSubViews

Comment: what if there are multiple elements in the cell? There has to be a simple way to do something for all of them rather than writing preferredMaxLayoutWidth for everyone?

Comment: in my experience , you can set its preferredMaxLayoutWidth based on the screen width ,this will make it simple to use

Comment: @Nil ,and the core reason for this problem ,it's that after the cell's layoutSubView is executed, all its subViews may not get the correct width , and the subViews will get the correct width when their own layoutSubviews is get called , I don't know my words can be understood or not , you can write a demo , and you will get clear